# extract text from span class with bs4

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

Im trying to extract course lenght (from Course content) from udemy webside

url: `https://www.udemy.com/course/ultimate-investment-banking-course/`

so what im expecting is:
1h 41m

```
<div class="ud-text-sm" data-purpose="curriculum-stats"><span class="curriculum--content-length--5Nict">14 sections • 51 lectures • <span><span>1h&nbsp;41m</span> total length</span></span></div>
```

im trying like this:

```py
res = requests.get("https://www.udemy.com/course/ultimate-investment-banking-course/")
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")

soup.select(".curriculum--content-length--5Nict")
or
soup.find("span",{"class":"curriculum--content-length--5Nict"})
```

but returns empty

Comment: What does request.get return? Your soup commands should return the inner part of the span.

Answer (score 1):

Some of contents are loaded dynamically, so you have to take a look into your browsers dev tools on xhr tab to locate the resources and grab the content directly from these.

So check for `course_id` with `beautifulsoup` and use the value to request the api.

##### Example

*Example is imited to your question - Take a closer look into [https://www.udemy.com/api-2.0/course-landing-components/{course_id}/me/?components=curriculum_context"](https://www.udemy.com/api-2.0/course-landing-components/%7Bcourse_id%7D/me/?components=curriculum_context%22)).json() to get an idea what else is provided, that fits your needs and access like from a dict.*

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(
    requests.get('https://www.udemy.com/course/ultimate-investment-banking-course/',
                headers={'user-agent':'some agent'}
                ).text)

course_id = soup.body.get('data-clp-course-id')

data = requests.get(f"https://www.udemy.com/api-2.0/course-landing-components/{course_id}/me/?components=curriculum_context").json()['curriculum_context']['data']
data['estimated_content_length_text']
```